Повторение действий в браузерах
Как реализовать повторение действий с одного браузера на всех других?
Например я захожу на сайт, нажимаю кнопку или ввожу текст и то же самое повторяется на 2х или 3х браузерах.
Например:

Нажал на кнопку "Отправить" и во всех остальных браузерах параллельно нажимается эта кнопка
Вписал текст в какой-то плэйсхолдер этот текст вписывается во все остальные браузеры

Похожее расширение для Chrome:

BetStorm (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ceB0-teZtdk)

# Браузеры подключаются через port
async with async_playwright() as p:
    for port in self.browser_ports:
        browser = await p.chromium.connect_over_cdp(f"http://localhost:{port}")

Python, Playwright

Здравствуйте, не могли бы вы описать чуть более конкретно что вы хотите сделать?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

@ШвеевАлексей дополнил
